# multiple SELECT FROM multi tables and SORT by date

Tags: php, mysql, database, union

I am looking a way to select multi data from multi tables `WHERE uid = :uid`
and `sort` them by `data`.

some thing like this :

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * from comments) AND
    (SELECT * from likes) AND
    (SELECT * from photos) AND
    (SELECT * from messages) WHERE uid = :uid ORDER BY date LIMIT 30
```

Actually, in a profile timeline I need to show `likes` , `comments` , `photos` and ... And all of these parts should be `sort by date` with `limitation` ...

**EDIT :**

```
Select cid,comment,pid,date from `ctg_comments` where uid = 69
UNION
Select pid,date from `ctg_likes` where uid = 69
UNION
Select address,postid,date from `ctg_photos` where byuid = 69
UNION
Select postid,date from `ctg_reservation` where uid=69
Order by date limit 30
```

I need some of every table column but they are not same to use UNION .

Thanks .

Comment: At a prfile time line I need to show likes , comments , photos and ... And all of this parts should sort by date with limition ...

Comment: you can use left join in MySQL query.

Comment: @VikasRana I am trying But how to do ?!

Comment: A sample of data of each tables and an expecting result would help. Right now, your question does not make sens.

Comment: is there any relationship between tables?

Comment: user id is same with all tables with `uid` column name , and `date` is column for sort them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from comments where uid=:uid
UNION
Select * from likes where uid:uid
UNION
Select * from photos where uid:uid
UNION
Select * from messages where uid:uid
Order by date limit 30
```

This solution requires that the columns from each tables are of same type, the resultset will take the columns names of the first table. If only one or two columns differs on each table, you can just extract the similar columns by naming them instead of extracting all columns :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Extracting all columns with * is usually frowned on, because your code become unreadble without knowledge of the database. And it might extract more data than needed.

With your data structure you might want to try this (I guessed the column type, so correct it if needed) :

```
Select 'comment' as type, 'none' as address, cid, comment, pid, date from `ctg_comments` where uid = 69
UNION
Select 'like' as type, 'none' as address, -1 as cid, 'none' as comment, pid, date from `ctg_likes` where uid = 69
UNION
Select 'photo'as type, address, -1 as cid, postid as pid, 'none' as comment, date from `ctg_photos` where byuid = 69
UNION
Select 'reservation' as type, 'none' as address, -1 as cid, postid as pid, 'none' as comment, date from `ctg_reservation` where uid=69
Order by date limit 30
```

I added a type column so it is easier to deal with in php after (you just test this field with a switch case instead of testing if address == 'none' or cid == -1 ...).

Comment: Thanks @laurent , But UNION is working with same columns   : #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: That is why you need to name them instead of using *, like if all tables have date, id, string1, string2 then your select will be : select date, id, string1, string2 from...

Comment: If your tables have totally differents columns, then making a request to extract all will not have much sense even if it is doable using left join and conditional testing for each field. I will highly recommand to extract all first 30 rows from each table sorted by date in different resultset and deal with it in php.

Comment: See my new answer, the main idea is to have the same number of fields extracted of the same type (varchar, integer,...) so you have to fill missing fields with placeholders.

Comment: Thank you so much @Laurent , What is your suggestion ? using this query or use 4 query and fetch data then use with php ?

Comment: This query should do the job, i will suggest 4 query and deal with it with php only if it had many more columns and hardly any of the same type.